# How to loop and show error message until input the file can be opened

Tags: python, file-io

I need to define a function called `open_file(prompt_str)`. This function receives a string which is the message to display when prompting the user to enter a file name. The program will try to open the file. An error message should be shown if the file cannot be opened. This function will loop until it receives proper input and successfully opens the file. It returns a file pointer.

```
fp = open(filename, "r ")
```

For this homework assignment, I was given the already defined variable `Option`.

Code:

```
OPTION = "\nMenu\
\n\t1: Display data by year\
\n\t2: Display data by country\
\n\t3: Display country codes\
\n\t4: Stop the Program\
\n\n\tEnter option number: "
"Enter the filename to read: "
"File not found! Try Again!"
"Enter year: "
"Year needs to be between 2009 and 2017. Try Again!"
"Do you want to plot (yes/no)? "
"Enter country code: "
"Country code is not found! Try Again!"
"\nCountry Code Reference"
"Invalid option. Try Again!"
"\nThanks for using this program!"

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

MIN_YEAR = 2009
MAX_YEAR = 2017

def open_file(prompt_str):
    '''
        WRITE DOCSTRING HERE!!!
    '''
    filename = input(Option)
    #Do i use a if statment or try except to check whether file is able to be opened 
    fp = open(filename, "r ", encoding = "utf-8 ")

    pass
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I have updated the question to the link with the code I have so far

Comment: Generally speaking, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) However it looks like @eyllanesc converted your image into text and inserted it into you question for you (although he left out a couple of lines at the end — possibly because they don't do much of anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function receives a string which is the message to diplay when prompting the user to enter a filename

That's what you want to pass to input, not OPTION. Note: `Option` is undefined in your code

> This function will loop until it receives proper input and successfully opens the file

You're missing a loop

> It returns a file pointer

You'll need to replace the pass with a return statement

---

For example

```
def open_file(prompt_str):
    while True:
        filename = input(prompt_str)
        try:
            return open(filename)
        except IOError:
            print(filename + " doesn't exist")
```